# Angular Pipe could not be found in Jasmine test

Tags: angular6, karma-jasmine

I'm getting an error using Jasmine to test one of my angular 6 components:

The pipe 'paginate' could not be found ("]Item of activityLogDisplay.data | paginate: config; let index = index"       (click)="): ng:///DynamicTestModule/ActivitylogComponent.html@59:34
'pagination-controls' is not a known element:

I'm using NgxPaginationModule that I installed with the following command:

```
npm install ngx-pagination --save
```

So, note that I'm not using a custom pipe that I created myself, I'm using one that belongs to a package that I downloaded. My component test is failing on the use of a pipe and not on testing the pipe itself. Here's what my use of the pagination pipe looks like in my html template:

```
 <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" 
    *ngFor="let alItem of activityLogDisplay.data | paginate: config; let index = index" 
    (click)="toggleALView(alItem.index)">
```

Here's what my spec.ts file looks like (pretty much out of the box):

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ActivitylogComponent } from './activitylog.component';

describe('ActivitylogComponent', () => {
  let component: ActivitylogComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ActivitylogComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ActivitylogComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ActivitylogComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I've tried adding the import of NgxPaginationModule to the spec.ts file:

```
import { NgxPaginationModule } from 'ngx-pagination';
```

And I've included it in the declarations area of the TestBed config:

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ActivitylogComponent, NgxPaginationModule ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

The error message changes to:

```
Failed: Unexpected module 'NgxPaginationModule' declared by the module 
'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
```

In my app.module.ts file, I've got NgxPaginationModule listed in the imports array and not the declarations array:

```
import { NgxPaginationModule } from 'ngx-pagination';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ActivitylogComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgxPaginationModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes,{useHash:true})
  ],
  providers: [IndexService, AdminIndexService],
  bootstrap: [LandingpageComponent]
})
```

Any ideas what I need to do to get this test to work?

Answer (score 4):

Figured out my problem. I needed to add NgxPaginationModule as an import to the test bed configureTestingModule area in my spec file:

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports : [
        NgxPaginationModule
      ],
      declarations: [ 
        ActivitylogComponent
       ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Comment: I have the same error and i have the  same configuration in my spec.ts

Answer (score 1):

**FIX:**
Do the following changes:

1. In your local module add your `KeyValue` pipe in `declarations`.
2. In `spec` file add `KeyValue` pipe's class name in `declarations`.
3. Add in `providers` as well if you get error like `NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[PipeName -> PipeName]:  NullInjectorError: No provider for PipeName!`.

**Your local spec file where error came**

```
beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                CommonModule,
                RouterTestingModule,
                HttpClientTestingModule,
                NotifierModule,
                ReactiveFormsModule
            ],
            providers: [
              ConfigureDeviceComponent
            ],
            declarations: [
              // Add your pipe here
            ]
        });
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ConfigureDeviceComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        component.ngOnInit();
    });
```

**Your local module file where your current component is running**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...], Include your pipe here
  imports: [...],
  providers: [...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72787641/10373693