# Angular tests - The pipe 'keyvalue' could not be found

Tags: angular, jasmine

I tried writing some tests and I get this error message: Error: NG0302: The pipe 'keyvalue' could not be found!. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0302.

This keyValue pipe is in CommonModule, so I import this module to spec.ts file and it's still doesn't work.

```
beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                CommonModule,
                RouterTestingModule,
                HttpClientTestingModule,
                NotifierModule,
                ReactiveFormsModule
            ],
            providers: [ConfigureDeviceComponent]
        });
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ConfigureDeviceComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        component.ngOnInit();
    });
```

Does someone have some suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**FIX:**
Do the following changes:

1. In your local module add your `KeyValue` pipe in `declarations`.
2. In `spec` file add `KeyValue` pipe's class name in `declarations`.
3. Add in `providers` as well if you get error like `NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[PipeName -> PipeName]:  NullInjectorError: No provider for PipeName!`.

**Your local spec file where error came**

```
beforeEach(async () => {
        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                CommonModule,
                RouterTestingModule,
                HttpClientTestingModule,
                NotifierModule,
                ReactiveFormsModule
            ],
            providers: [
              ConfigureDeviceComponent
            ],
            declarations: [
              // Add your pipe here
            ]
        });
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ConfigureDeviceComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        component.ngOnInit();
    });
```

**Your local module file where your current component is running**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...], Include your pipe here
  imports: [...],
  providers: [...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to provide a component instead of declaring it. Maybe this is why angular thinks it's a pipe. Try changing `providers` for `declarations`

I'm unsure this is the right answer tho, so let me know if it works

Comment: I use this keyValue pipe in my component, but when I write tests for this component I get this error. But I solved it by adding my own module where I declared this component to the imports in test file.